# Complicated nested json loops to store with extjs

Tags: json, extjs, store, extjs6

I'm using a geojson extracted from naturalearthdata which looks like that :
[image]

All I want is to catch the NAME of each feature in order to display them in a grid (live search grid.. BTW is it efficient for 2000 names?)
But I can't access to all the name with root property. I tried to loop into all the features

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.Places', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.places',
    requires : ['myApp.model.PlacesModel',
                'myApp.view.main.MainModel'],
    id: 'Places',
    model: 'myApp.model.PlacesModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/resources/data/coord.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            transform: {
                fn: function(data) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.features.length -1; i++){
                        names_places.push(data.features[i].properties.NAME);
                    }
                    debugger;
                    return names_places;
                },
                scope: this
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But the debugger sent me that result which I don't understand :
[image]

Especially when the array looks good :
[image]

What is the good way to catch only the NAME? Does the return has to look to a json?

Comment: I think you need to return an array of proper `myApp.model.PlacesModel` records instead of just an array of strings in `transform`. The docs say it should return a data object http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-modern/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-transform

Comment: you can probably just say the `rootProperty` is `features`.  Then, in the model fields add a field with a [`mapping` property](https://bt.associatesys.local/documentation/extjs5/ext-docs-5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field-cfg-mapping), for instance, `mapping: 'properties.NAME'`

Comment: @weeksdev That works thank you very much ! If you want to post it as an answer I'll close the question, if not I remove the question tonight

Comment: @So4ne i posted it as an answer, i think this question would be good to preserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mapping` attribute on the `fields` array in your model definition to map the correct attribute in the json to a field.

You set the `rootProperty` to `features` for the `reader`.

Then in your `fields` array something similar to this

```
fields: [
    { name: 'myCustomField', mapping: 'properties.NAME' }
]
```